# Update and Varbinary(Max)

Tags: t-sql

I want to set the value of sequence from row 1 to row 2.

[image]

**If I run:**

```
Update [dbo].[TS_TaskSequence] 
set [Sequence] = 'the value of sequence' 
Where [TS_ID] = '16777234'
```

**I get:**

> Implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

[image]

How do I convert it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `CAST()` (`CONVERT()`) the hard-coded value in your query as a `VARBINARY(MAX)` because by default a value in single quotes in a query is natively treated as a `VARCHAR` data type.

You could also use the following `CROSS JOIN` query (without hard-coding the value) to completely eliminate the need to cast anything since your source and destination fields in the query are already both of type `VARBINARY(MAX)`:

```
UPDATE TS2
SET TS2.Sequence = TS1.Sequence
FROM dbo.TS_TaskSequence AS TS1
CROSS JOIN dbo.TS_TaskSequence AS TS2
WHERE TS1.TS_ID = '16777230'
    AND TS2.TS_ID = '16777234'
```

Comment: I'll work with that, thank you!